# Is it possible to use SQLite from JDBC in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jdbc

i am populating sqlite data base table using java with JDBC. and later i want to use that table in android device to select some data from it and make some calculations. is it possible?

kindly please advice.

Comment: Android has its own set of api's to query database. Make use of it.

Comment: @Shriram u mean that, the table generated from Java JDBC, can be used in Android?

Comment: SqLlite comes with android by default. You can use the schema which you have used in java.

Comment: @Shriram would u please tell me, which yields better performance concernig accessing the database and retrieve records, is when the database is saved in the hardDrive or in the memory?

Comment: You cannot keep your complete db in the memory which will be stored in as separate disk/system memory.

Comment: @Shriram would u please tell me if there is any configurations i should do in Android API to set the path to the database table i generated using java JDBC